# Running PowerShell scripts in Visual Studio 2019 solution

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

We have a Nuget package that handles our project references that are used in dozens of separate solutions and projects. It works great, except that we have to change each reference's "Copy local" property to false. I see that the install.ps1 and uninstall.ps1 are no longer supported in Visual Studio, however Init.ps1 is.

I'm trying to figure out how to run a PowerShell script in Visual Studio with a solution open to test the changing of the reference properties. I've read through a few articles, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for and it seems as if I'm missing something very basic. Any help or nudges in the right direction would be very helpful.

Thank you!